# Group name is not polling data

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have topic with messages, and having consumer with group name as "KafkaConsumerExample". when i restart consumer, all the messages from topic was received without issues. but, when i change the name of my consumer group with same consumer code, consumer is not pulling data from topic ? what would be reason for this issue, changing the consumer name changes the behavior from topic. can you please help here ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot consume messages again using the same consumer group name. This is because kafka maintains offsets to maintain logs of the data it has consumed. This ensures kafka's exactly once semantics.

If you wish to consume the same data again from the topic, you need to change the name of the consumer group.

I hope this helps! let me know if I addressed your question or if there is anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that when a new consumer group is used to read a topic, the first messages read are just after the messages already read by some other consumer group ( see [auto.offset.reset](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) explanation). This consumer config property lets you start reading at the latest offset (default, so you can start roughly where other groups have left off) but you want to set this property to "earliest" in order to force the consumer to read from the first message in each partition.